# How to change the Container Entrypoint in Buildpacks?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, buildpack, entry-point

I am using [buildpacks](https://buildpacks.io/) to build a container image of node js application.

```
the default entrypoint is cnb/process/web that will execute npm start.
```

I need to change the cmd & arguments from  **npm start** to **node {file.js}**

Here's the command that I used to build image

> ```
> pack build --builder gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1 {image-name}
> ```

is there any way to change the container entrypoint of the buildpack image? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you try to add a `Procfile` with `web: <command to run>` entry in your code base?

Comment: Yes! finally found and added that. it worked!  thanks for the information @guillaumeblaquiere
is there any other work around for this?

Comment: I don't know other ways!

Answer (score 1):

Some buildpacks support a `Procfile`, which allows you to configure the process used to launch the image like this:

```
web: npm start
```

For a more buildpacks-native approach see the documentation on  launch processes. https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/run-an-app/

Answer (score 0):

There's another neat option, if you use nodejs buildpacks. [The docs state](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/nodejs/#specify-a-custom-entrypoint) to add `BP_LAUNCHPOINT` as a `--env` parameter like this:

```
pack build --builder gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1 --env BP_LAUNCHPOINT="file.js" {image-name}
```

When running the image as a container, it will start with the command `node file.js`, where `file.js` lies within the `workspace` directory in the containers root.

In my case I had a Nuxt 3 build app, where my launchpoint is this: `--env BP_LAUNCHPOINT=".output/server/index.mjs"` and thus uses `node` to start the file `workspace/.output/server/index.mjs` inside the root of the container.